# fail2ban keeps trying to ban again

Tags: fail2ban, cloudflare

I have an issue getting fail2ban to do what I want. I use a action which bans the IP on CLoudFlare, that means that still a lot of requests get through until everything has been updated on Cloudflare´s end (and therefore the user is no longer able to access the site).

Until that happened, fail2ban tries to ban the IP over and over again, causing it to send thousands (in case of an ddos) of request to cloudflare which takes a damn long time and therefore won't ban any other attackers until its done with the previous (already banned) ones.

So, is there a way to stop fail2ban from attempting to ban them again, and just ignore them?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure that the ip-blacklist file exists
# otherwise we go ahead and create it
if [ ! -e "/etc/fail2ban/ip.blacklist" ] ; then
    touch "/etc/fail2ban/ip.blacklist"
fi

if [[ $1 = ban ]]; then
    if ! grep -q "$2" /etc/fail2ban/ip.blacklist; then
        # Store the IP as we need it later to check if the user is already banned
        echo "$2" >> /etc/fail2ban/ip.blacklist

        # Submit the ban request
    fi 
elif [[ $1 = unban ]]; then
    # Remove the IP from the blacklist 
    perl -ni -e "print unless (/^$2$/);" /etc/fail2ban/ip.blacklist
    #sed -i '/^$2$/d' /etc/fail2ban/ip.blacklist

    # Submit the unban request
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a banned IPs list and adding the IPs to it when issuing the ban request.  In the action script ignore ban requests if the IP is in the list.  You will also need to change the unban action to remove the IP from the banned IP list.  Create a script such as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define ourbanfile
banFile=ip.blacklist

# Ensure we have a banFile will be created if missing
if [ ! -e ${banFile} ]; then
    touch ${banFile}
fi

# Ban or unban as desired
if [[ $1 = ban ]]; then
    if ! grep -q "$2" ${banFile}; then
        # Store the IP as we need it later to check if the user is already banned
        echo "$2" >> ${banFile}

        # Submit the ban request
    fi
elif [[ $1 = unban ]]; then
    # Remove the IP from the blacklist
    perl -ni -e "print unless (/^$2\$/);" ${banFile}
    #sed -i '/^$2$/d' ${banFile}

    # Submit the unban request
fi

# Cat banfile if running on terminal (testing)
tty -s  && cat ${banFile}

# EOF
```

Your actions would be:

```
actionban = /path/to/script ban <IP>
actionunban = /path/to/script unban <IP>
```

Comment: I added this check ```if ! grep -q '<ip>' "/etc/fail2ban/ip.blacklist"; then XXX fi```, it writes the ip correctly to the file but for some reason it continues to attempting to ban the ip over and over again. Not sure why..

Comment: I added the code to the question. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Michael include the call to ban the IP address inside the if statement.

Comment: Its there, just removed it before posting it here as it contains sensitive data. Buts thats not the point, it should not even go inside the IF statement anymore when the user is banned, but it still does.

Comment: @Michael I've updated my answer with a sample script and related actions.  I did not test the script, you should verify it manually before putting it into production. Under high volumes of ban/unban traffic it may not update the blacklist file correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why do you think that it might not update the list correctly under high volumes? Also, do you think that it might be better and faster to use sed instead of perl to remove the line?

Comment: There seems to be an issue. When I run the script manually it works fine, but when fail2ban is using it as an action it shows: fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.d/cloudflare-blacklist.sh ban <IP> returned 200

Comment: I updated the code in the question. Of course I removed the sensitive data again. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Michael Updated answer with a tested script.  Remove pattern should be '^$2\$' rather than '^$2$'. It is testable from the keyboard,

Comment: I really don't get it. On the terminal it works as expected, but when fail2ban is using it, it does not even create the ban file nor does it write to it. It does also not execute the ban request. Not sure why it does not work. On the terminal everything works fine. I don't understand what it does though, I expect the ban request to take the most time as it is an external request, currently fail2ban still shows the "already banned" message every second. I would expect it to show them way faster if it does not do anything at all.

Comment: @Michael  Try setting the ban file in /tmp.   If fail2ban is not running as root it can't create the file in /etc.

Comment: I just set the permission to 777 for testing and it still does not work. And as I said, it does not even execute the ban action :(

Comment: I have the feeling that fail2ban is using a special envornment. Is it possible to implement the actions directly into the fail2ban jail instead of having it in a own script?

Comment: Okay, just implemented it directly into the action. Now it does create the file and also writes to and also executes the ban request. BUT still, it takes way to long. Tail shows a new "already banned" message every second, so the check did not solve anything.. Not sure if this is an issue with fail2ban, no idea why it is do damn slow.

Comment: I doubt that there will be a solution for this problem? I honestly don't understand why there is no direct way to simply ignore already banned IPs.